# Cannot update PHP 5.4.16 to PHP 7.3

Tags: linux, php, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am using RedHat Linux 7.9. I am trying to upgrade PHP 5.4.16 to PHP 7.3 commands I find in blog posts and questions, don't work for me.

For instance:

```
[root@username src]# php --version
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2020 17:30:32) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
[root@username src]# wget -q http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
[root@username src]# wget -q https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
[root@username src]# rpm -i remi-release-7.rpm epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
warning: remi-release-7.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 00f97f56: NOKEY
    package epel-release-7-14.noarch is already installed
    package remi-release-7.9-2.el7.remi.noarch is already installed
[root@username src]# yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
Loaded plugins: langpacks
[root@username src]# yum install php
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Package php-5.4.16-48.el7.aarch64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@username src]# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No packages marked for update
[root@username src]# php --version
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2020 17:30:32) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

So, how I can update PHP to newer version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are trying to use "remi" repository which is only for x86_64, but you are running aarch64. You can try https://repo.drpixel.fr/ which provides "some " rebuild of the same RPM for aarch64

Comment: See See https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues/214 aarch64 is now available for EL-9